# java metrics aggregation counters

Tags: java, metrics, codahale-metrics

I'm starting to use the metrics, and I have a "problem" about counters visualization, in this situation:

```
MetricRegistry.name("mymetrics", "count1", "")
MetricRegistry.name("mymetrics", "count2", "")
```

In this way I have two entry as:

```
-- Counters 
    mymetrics.count1
         count = 1000000
    mymetrics.count2
       count = 2000000
```

And the same in the JMX console,as:
[image]

So, is there a way to have the metrics like:

```
-- Counters   
      mymetrics
         count1 = 1000000
         count2 = 2000000
```

because I have lot counters and I'd like to have all of them in one entry.

Thank you.